# How to retrieve the value from the data attribute in node js via form submit with method post

Tags: forms, node.js, attributes, submit, pug

How to get the value from the data attribute in node js via form submit.
I want to get a 2nd information from user!

My first try was this:

Clientside:

```
input(type="submit" ,name="responseValue" , value="yes",  data="question1" )
input(type="submit" ,name="responseValue" , value="no",  data="question2" )
```

Serverside:

```
//works ok
var responseValue = req.body.responseValue;

//following does not work
var questionNumber = req.body.data
```

Is there any solution for this without a hidden field ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate string in the value field and then separate it at server side.
Your client side may look like this.

```
input(type="submit",name="responseValue", value="yes,question1")
```

Then at server side you can separate the string responseValue by the index of ','.

Comment: the submit button should only have the yes caption on the button grafic therefor this is not a solution